# Certificate of employment and back pay

Tags: resignation

I submitted to my employer my resignation letter with a 30 days notice, and informed them to immediately look for my replacement so I can train the newcomer  well enough since I may not be able to report for work everyday until my last day.
I made these informations clear on my resignation letter and my manager gladly signed on that.

These past few days, I've already incurred 3 absences and 2 undertimes but I made it pretty sure that my manager knows about and is aware that I cant report for work on the said days.

However I've learned that she is threatening me that I will not get my certificate of employment as well as my back pay if I continue to render more absences.

I find it unacceptable from my point of view since I always make sure that I still do my job as smooth as possible, and whenever I will not report for work, I immediately inform her beforehand.

What can I do in order to be sure to receive my back pay and my certificate of employment at the end of my notice period ?

Comment: If you're not showing up, then you're not performing smoothly, there seems to be a basic contradiction here. You can get sacked out of hand for that sort of behaviour.

Comment: Location?  Also - Likely to get closed as asking for legal advice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Clearly the solution is to just do your work as you're supposed to? A notice period doesn't change the requirements of the job: you still need to come in when you're supposed to and put in the hours required.

Comment: Having submitted your resignation has nothing to do with you having to show up regularly and punctual.

Answer (score 6):

As the others said, the 30days work doesn't affect your job requirements. You need to show up at work and complete all your tasks and duties. You can take a day off or you ca request for some hours off, but you still need to present at the office if in your employment contract doesn't say anything about having a special schedule after presenting your resignation letter. Hope this has been useful

Answer (score 0):

> and informed them to immediately look for my replacement so I can
>   train the newcomer well enough since I may not be able to report for
>   work everyday until my last day.

Two things: You don't inform an employer to do anything. I suspect you let them know you'd help train if they got someone instead of telling them what they're going to do.

Next, just because you say you may not be able to report, and even if they sign off, if you don't give specific terms that they sign off on, you're still obligated to adhere to the initial contract. In most places, ambiguity of contract (or contract addendum, which it seems like what you are trying to present) will fall back to the earlier contract or in favor of the more specific terms of any part of an agreement.

Finally, if you want your back pay enough, fulfill your end of the agreement. This should be a point of pride and integrity. If you're not working, you're not earning the pay they're "threatening" to hold.